# Rad Studio, Firemonkey ios TWebBrowser seems above all objects

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, twebbrowser

I'm using Firmonkey (Rad Studio) for an IOS app.  I'm using a TWebBrowser object but this seems to stay above all objects.

I tried to right-click the TWebBrowser object and click Send to Back, but it did not.

Does anyone know any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, There are no solution for it. Because **TWebBrowser** is a native component, which is always on top of all controls.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav, You know any alternative component or alternative solutions ?

Comment: @yilmazca, I don't know.

Comment: Z-order issues in FireMonkey are scheduled to be addressed in RAD Studio 10.3. Don't expect a fix for earlier versions