# Issue with BringToFront in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have two controls on my form.

1. TWebBrowser with Align set to Client
2. TMemo with Align set to None

I want to display TMemo on top of TWebBrowser for a particular scenario and for that am using Memo.BringToFront but it does nothing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `TWebBrowser` is known for its forceful on-top nature. I'm pretty sure there is still no solution. Even if you put it inside a tab sheet, and go to another tab, you still see it... There are questions here on SO about this already too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352847/rad-studio-firemonkey-ios-twebbrowser-seems-above-all-objects But I can't mark as duplicate because it's never been accepted. I abandoned an entire FMX project because of this issue.

Comment: Z-order issues in FireMonkey are scheduled to be addressed in RAD Studio 10.3. Don't expect a fix for earlier versions

Comment: @RemyLebeau Are you confident `TWebBrowser` will be among the things fixed? Because AFAIK, similar issues still exist to this day on the VCL version.

Comment: @JerryDodge there is no way to know if or how it will be fixed until it has been released. I'm just stating that z-order fixes are on the current roadmap

Answer (score 2):

`TWebBrowser` Is a particular firemonkey Control. Firemonkey control are "paint" according to their z-order on a openGL surface (ie: the form). but TwebBrowser is a native control that is draw on another surface that is placed on the top of the form, hidding in this way everything back to it.

The only way you can do is to show you memo inside another window on the top of the TwebBrowser. for this you can use a native Memo. As far as i know their is only one native memo implemented on android (delphi already have some that work on ios/windows) it's https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But for now I want to stick with FMX components. Although solution is ugly I am using this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757559/multiview-android-delphi-with-twebbrowser

Comment: maybe you can try to use another form to show to memo. with a little luck it's will be like another surface and it's will be put on the top of the webbrowser ... but i m not sure